# how create copies of xml within its node using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

i have xml like this :

```
<p>
                  <p1>DISTRIBUTOR</p1>
                  <p2>f</p2>
                  <p3>us</p3>
                  <p4>5</p4>
                  <c>
                     <c1>SOCIAL_MEDIA</c1>
                     <c2>www.facebook.com</c2>
                     <c3>facebook</c3>
                  </c>
                  <c>
                     <c1>EMAIL</c1>
                     <c2>www.gmail.com</c2>
                     <c3>gmail</c3>
                  </c>
               </p>
```

i want output in the following way using xslt, it is basically creating a copy of its part:

```
       <p>
          <p1>DISTRIBUTOR</p1>
          <p2>f</p2>
          <p3>us</p3>
          <p4>5</p4>
          <c>
              <p1>DISTRIBUTOR</p1>
             <p2>f</p2>
             <p3>us</p3>
             <p4>5</p4>
             <c1>SOCIAL_MEDIA</c1>
             <c2>www.facebook.com</c2>
             <c3>facebook</c3>
          </c>
          <c>
              <p1>DISTRIBUTOR</p1>
             <p2>f</p2>
             <p3>us</p3>
             <p4>5</p4>
             <c1>EMAIL</c1>
             <c2>www.gmail.com</c2>
             <c3>gmail</c3>
          </c>
       </p>
```

can anybody help me out....
i tried using array creation for the element which is to be copied but ended up confusing the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">    
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/p/node()[starts-with(name(), 'p')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```